# How do I use express middleware to act as an API responder?

Tags: express, coffeescript, middleware

My route definition is:

`app.put '/api/v1/user/oldest', userController.oldestAndUpdate, responder`

in `userController`, I have:

```
exports.oldestAndUpdate = (req, res, next) ->
  doSomeStuff, (err, results) ->
    return next err if err
    req.apiResponse = results
    next()
```

in my `responder`, I have:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) ->
  response = req.apiResponse
  response.status = 'ok'

  res.json response
```

But how do I handle the error case? If the `next(err)` is hit, how will my responder know there's an error?

Comment: FYI, you'll get more responses if you post your code in JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is ever an error passed to `next`, the middleware chain and routing is stopped, and it skips straight to the error handling middleware.

The error handling middleware is special, as it has four arguments: err, req, res, next. Internally, express checks the arity (number of arguments) of every middleware handler, and if it has 4 it's used as the error handler. From here you can respond in the same style as the rest of your API.

There is an example error handler in the [expressjs guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling).